# 16215#0: "types" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/mime.types:1

Tags: nginx, types, directive

I'm getting this error in the error log when starting/restarting nginx (1.4.6 on Ubuntu 14.04, with php5-fpm)

2015/01/01 13:27:38 [emerg] 16215#0: "types" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/mime.types:1

Nginx runs fine, i.e. even though it indicates [fail] when starting/restarting, it runs ok.

Any idea what I could try to fix this?

/etc/nginx/mime.types contains the following:

```
types {
    text/html                               html htm shtml;
    text/css                                css;
    text/xml                                xml rss;
    image/gif                               gif;
    image/jpeg                              jpeg jpg;
    application/x-javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                    atom;

    text/mathml                             mml;
    text/plain                              txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor        jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                        wml;
    text/x-component                        htc;

    image/png                               png;
    image/tiff                              tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                      wbmp;
    image/x-icon                            ico;
    image/x-jng                             jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                          bmp;
    image/svg+xml                           svg svgz;

    application/java-archive                jar war ear;
    application/json                        json;
    application/mac-binhex40                hqx;
    application/msword                      doc;
    application/pdf                         pdf;
    application/postscript                  ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                         rtf;
    application/vnd.ms-excel                xls;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint           ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc                wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml    kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz        kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed             7z;
    application/x-cocoa                     cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff         jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file            jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                  run;
    application/x-perl                      pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                     prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed            rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager    rpm;
    application/x-sea                       sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash           swf;
    application/x-stuffit                   sit;
    application/x-tcl                       tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert              der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall                 xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                   xhtml;
    application/zip                         zip;

    application/octet-stream                bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream                deb;
    application/octet-stream                dmg;
    application/octet-stream                eot;
    application/octet-stream                iso img;
    application/octet-stream                msi msp msm;
    application/ogg                         ogx;

    audio/midi                              mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                              mpga mpega mp2 mp3 m4a;
    audio/ogg                               oga ogg spx;
    audio/x-realaudio                       ra;
    audio/webm                              weba;

    video/3gpp                              3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp4                               mp4;
    video/mpeg                              mpeg mpg mpe;
    video/ogg                               ogv;
    video/quicktime                         mov;
    video/webm                              webm;
    video/x-flv                             flv;
    video/x-mng                             mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                          asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                          wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                         avi;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK it was a mistake I had made in my nginx.conf. In the http directive there was one too many }. I fixed that and no more error.